# Double Latin letters in Unicode (ligatures)

Tags: encoding, unicode, characters, combine

What Unicode characters are there where two Latin letters are joined together in a ligature to form a single Unicode character? Similar to this type of character: **㎐** or **æ**

I looked in the [Unicode charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) but there was too much to sort though.

Comment: Valid question, I've had to use ligatures before and pre-Unicode was a pain.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on your definition for “ligature”. For example, “æ” is a ligature by origin, and still regarded as a ligature of “a” and “e” in some contexts (e.g., when writing Latin words in English), but in many languages, it has become an independent letter (just like “ä” in some other languages – it, too, is historically a ligature of “a” and “e”). The character “㎐” is a special form of the identifier Hz, for hertz, to be used in East Asian writing systems only.

The only ligature characters that correspond to *typographic* ligatures of Latin letters are those in the Alphabetic Presentation forms: ligatures for ff, fi, fl, ffi, ffl, ſt, and st. They have been included for compatibility only (to let you represent existing data where such ligatures appear as characters), rather than for quality typesetting.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to [decompose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character#Comparing_precomposed_and_decomposed_characters) the letter into characters by [normalizing it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) to [NKFD](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/), then just check if the output are Latin letters or not. Here's a simple Python script to do that

```py
import unicodedata

for c in range(0, 0x10FFFF + 1):
    d = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', chr(c))
    if len(d) > 1 and d.isascii() and d.isalpha():
        print("U+%04X (%s): %s\n" % (c, chr(c), d))
```

Unfortunately many ligatures like [æ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86) or [œ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%92) aren't decomposable because they're not considered [orthographic ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature):

> The character Æ (lower case æ; in ancient times named æsc) when used in the Danish, Norwegian, or Icelandic languages, or Old English, is not a typographic ligature. It is a distinct letter—a vowel—and when alphabetised, is given a different place in the alphabetic order.
>
> ...
>
> Note, however, that ligatures such as æ and œ are not used to replace arbitrary "ae" or "oe" sequences; it is generally considered incorrect to write "does" as "dœs".

Below is the result in Unicode 11.0.0 (checked with [`unicodedata.unidata_version`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.unidata_version))

```
U+0132 (Ĳ): IJ
U+0133 (ĳ): ij
U+01C7 (Ǉ): LJ
U+01C8 (ǈ): Lj
U+01C9 (ǉ): lj
U+01CA (Ǌ): NJ
U+01CB (ǋ): Nj
U+01CC (ǌ): nj
U+01F1 (Ǳ): DZ
U+01F2 (ǲ): Dz
U+01F3 (ǳ): dz
U+20A8 (₨): Rs
U+2116 (№): No
U+2120 (℠): SM
U+2121 (℡): TEL
U+2122 (™): TM
U+213B (℻): FAX
U+2161 (Ⅱ): II
U+2162 (Ⅲ): III
U+2163 (Ⅳ): IV
U+2165 (Ⅵ): VI
U+2166 (Ⅶ): VII
U+2167 (Ⅷ): VIII
U+2168 (Ⅸ): IX
U+216A (Ⅺ): XI
U+216B (Ⅻ): XII
U+2171 (ⅱ): ii
U+2172 (ⅲ): iii
U+2173 (ⅳ): iv
U+2175 (ⅵ): vi
U+2176 (ⅶ): vii
U+2177 (ⅷ): viii
U+2178 (ⅸ): ix
U+217A (ⅺ): xi
U+217B (ⅻ): xii
U+3250 (㉐): PTE
U+32CC (㋌): Hg
U+32CD (㋍): erg
U+32CE (㋎): eV
U+32CF (㋏): LTD
U+3371 (㍱): hPa
U+3372 (㍲): da
U+3373 (㍳): AU
U+3374 (㍴): bar
U+3375 (㍵): oV
U+3376 (㍶): pc
U+3377 (㍷): dm
U+337A (㍺): IU
U+3380 (㎀): pA
U+3381 (㎁): nA
U+3383 (㎃): mA
U+3384 (㎄): kA
U+3385 (㎅): KB
U+3386 (㎆): MB
U+3387 (㎇): GB
U+3388 (㎈): cal
U+3389 (㎉): kcal
U+338A (㎊): pF
U+338B (㎋): nF
U+338E (㎎): mg
U+338F (㎏): kg
U+3390 (㎐): Hz
U+3391 (㎑): kHz
U+3392 (㎒): MHz
U+3393 (㎓): GHz
U+3394 (㎔): THz
U+3396 (㎖): ml
U+3397 (㎗): dl
U+3398 (㎘): kl
U+3399 (㎙): fm
U+339A (㎚): nm
U+339C (㎜): mm
U+339D (㎝): cm
U+339E (㎞): km
U+33A9 (㎩): Pa
U+33AA (㎪): kPa
U+33AB (㎫): MPa
U+33AC (㎬): GPa
U+33AD (㎭): rad
U+33B0 (㎰): ps
U+33B1 (㎱): ns
U+33B3 (㎳): ms
U+33B4 (㎴): pV
U+33B5 (㎵): nV
U+33B7 (㎷): mV
U+33B8 (㎸): kV
U+33B9 (㎹): MV
U+33BA (㎺): pW
U+33BB (㎻): nW
U+33BD (㎽): mW
U+33BE (㎾): kW
U+33BF (㎿): MW
U+33C3 (㏃): Bq
U+33C4 (㏄): cc
U+33C5 (㏅): cd
U+33C8 (㏈): dB
U+33C9 (㏉): Gy
U+33CA (㏊): ha
U+33CB (㏋): HP
U+33CC (㏌): in
U+33CD (㏍): KK
U+33CE (㏎): KM
U+33CF (㏏): kt
U+33D0 (㏐): lm
U+33D1 (㏑): ln
U+33D2 (㏒): log
U+33D3 (㏓): lx
U+33D4 (㏔): mb
U+33D5 (㏕): mil
U+33D6 (㏖): mol
U+33D7 (㏗): PH
U+33D9 (㏙): PPM
U+33DA (㏚): PR
U+33DB (㏛): sr
U+33DC (㏜): Sv
U+33DD (㏝): Wb
U+33FF (㏿): gal
U+FB00 (ﬀ): ff
U+FB01 (ﬁ): fi
U+FB02 (ﬂ): fl
U+FB03 (ﬃ): ffi
U+FB04 (ﬄ): ffl
U+FB05 (ﬅ): st
U+FB06 (ﬆ): st
U+1F12D (): CD
U+1F12E (): WZ
U+1F14A (): HV
U+1F14B (): MV
U+1F14C (): SD
U+1F14D (): SS
U+1F14E (): PPV
U+1F14F (): WC
U+1F16A (): MC
U+1F16B (): MD
U+1F190 (): DJ
```

If you also want to get additional characters with diacritics then use this

```py
for c in range(0, 0x10FFFF + 1):
    ch = chr(c)
    d = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', ch)
    s = "".join([c for c in d if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
    if 1 < len(s) < len(d) and s.isalpha() and s.isascii():
        print("U+%04X (%s): %s" % (c, ch, d))
```

Result:

```
U+01C4 (Ǆ): DŽ
U+01C5 (ǅ): Dž
U+01C6 (ǆ): dž
```

Comment: TIL unicode has mappings for ff and fi but not tt and ti, how strange as those ligatures are common side effects of OCR. Hope this helps the next traveler on this road. 

Comment: @G.N. all those things are due to historical reasons. There were older charsets that map those characters so [Unicode must also have a code point for them to maintain the zero-loss round trip conversion policy](https://superuser.com/a/1602791/241386)

Answer (score 0):

Use the OS utilities to get that kind of information. Select a Unicode font in the following:

Microsoft Windows OS has Character Map.

Apple Macintosh OS X has Key Caps.

Linux distributions with GUI often have Character Map.

The Linux utility is quite easy to use, many of the fonts are UTF-8, select Latin in the Script selector and scroll through the list.

Comment: The problem is finding the characters, there are currently over a 100 thousand unicode characters.

Comment: Not really, if you're using Linux, it allows you to only select Latin which limits it down to only the Latin character set which only has 8 pages to view. You were asking only for the Latin Character Set out of the whole Unicode set, correct? Even by eyeballing, the Windows Character Map is fairly easy to use for just Latin. Did you bother looking?

Comment: There are tons of characters outside the Latin blocks that are composed of Latin characters so simply limiting to Latin like this doesn't work. ㎐ above is one example. Some others: Ⅻ, ⅷ, ㏒, ₧, ℻, , , , ...

Answer (score 0):

[Search Unicode character by drawing](http://shapecatcher.com/)

Though it seems not able to recognize Hz (㎐).

Latin small letter ae: æ
Unicode hexadecimal: 0xe6
In block: **Latin-1 Supplement**

Cyrillic small ligature a ie: ӕ
Unicode hexadecimal: 0x4d5
In block: **Cyrillic**

Comment: currently shapecatcher supports only 11817 characters, whereas Unicode have more than 100000 characters so obviously it'll miss a lot of cases. And the OP wants to find other letters, drawing like this doesn't help since there are so many combinations to try even if you have some software that can recognize all Unicode characters

Comment: @phuclv Understand. Do you have better ideas to help OP?

Comment: yes, just use write a script to do the lookup