# Why are the "copyright", "registered trademark" and "trademark" symbols considered emojis?

Tags: unicode, emoji

I've just spent days going through Hell and back figuring out how to remove all emojis from a string. It was more involved than I could ever have imagined.

However, as I had got it working, I made a simple test and through a very unlikely coincidence, I tested a copyright symbol to see if it was removed. It was. At first, I thought I had yet another bug in my system, but then I looked it up in the list and it actually *is* considered an emoji:

> `00A9 FE0F`; Basic_Emoji; copyright # E0.6   [1] (©️)
> `00AE FE0F`; Basic_Emoji; registered # E0.6   [1] (®️)
> `203C FE0F`; Basic_Emoji; double exclamation mark # E0.6   [1] (‼️)
> `2122 FE0F`; Basic_Emoji; trade mark # E0.6   [1] (™️)

Source: https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.1/emoji-sequences.txt

*All* of the other ones (thousands!) make sense, except for these 3-4 ones (the "!!" one is a grey area to me).

How come they officially consider the "copyright", "registered trademark" and "trademark" symbols to be emojis? Aren't they extremely formal and commonly used in all kinds of "important business" and academic papers? Not a crazy colorful smiley face?

Comment: Are you by any chance identical to the author of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1602456/203639)? If yes, you might want to look at [this](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts). Also, your endeavour smells strongly like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): Are you sure that removing all emojis from a string is really what you need?

Comment: Emoji's aren't necessarily informal, they are used in business documents too. If the "crazy colourful" part is what bothers you, use a monochrome emoji font like OpenMoji-Black instead of arbitrarily stripping characters out.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the things that seem "stupid" in Unicode exist just because they existed before in other encodings. Unicode is designed so that [round-trip conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_format_conversion) to old encodings is possible so you'll see codepoints for "characters" like ǋ, ǅ, Ⅷ, ㎉, ㎓, ﷽... because some people thought that those are useful for their countries' texts

> [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) has a principle to have round-trip compatibility with older standardized legacy encodings, so conversion of documents to Unicode do not lose information; they can be converted back. To achieve this, [Unicode compatibility characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_compatibility_characters) have been introduced.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_format_conversion#Character_encodings

Same to emojis. You can check [emoji sources](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/EmojiSources.txt) to know why an emoji was added to Unicode

> This file provides historical mappings between Unicode code points and sequences on one hand and [Shift-JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) codes for cell phone carrier symbols on the other hand. Each mapping is symmetric ("round trip"), for equivalent Unicode and carrier symbols or sequences.

The file contains 4 fields

- 0: Unicode code point or sequence
- 1: DoCoMo Shift-JIS code
- 2: KDDI Shift-JIS code
- 3: SoftBank Shift-JIS code

You can see that the © U+00A9, ®️ U+00AE, ‼️ U+203C and ™ U+2122 are all in the list

```
00A9;F9D6;F774;F7EE
00AE;F9DB;F775;F7EF
...
203C;F9A9;F3F1;
...
2122;F9D7;F76A;FBD7
```

So the answer is simply because they've been used as emojis by Japanese mobile phone carriers. The reason why those carriers added ©, ®️, ‼️ and ™ emojis is a different question